Is “thing” a good category?
Some alternative titles to this post could be:

“Dialectics of ‘thing’”
Is “thing” a type of thing?
Is “type” a thing?

As I have explored creating different formal models, my attention has regressed into what are known as “upper ontologies”, which are concerned with the most fundamental categories we model the world in, at all.
Unfortunately, the need to resolve these fundamental questions has led to new issues and complexity.
It seems like one elemental concept or primitive notion we can begin to work with, in presenting some structured description of the world, or of a system, is that of “thing”. I am considering some reasons why “thing” is not actually as simple as we would hope it to be:

There are things which lack “thing-ness”. To be specific, I mean that when we begin to populate our ontology with particular things, like a certain person or concept, the need for other paradigms or modalities arises, in what more we can say about the things: how they relate to each other, for example; actions undertaken by these things; and also, certain properties or aspects of actions and verbs, like their grammatical modality (such as “should go”). Compared to the concrete things we originally had, it does not at all feel like “should” is a thing; it is some way of transforming something (a verb); hence it lacks “thing-ness” and, as I said, is of “a different modality”. It inflects something; it is not anything on its own. So this suggests there are other fundamental categories in an ontology than “thing”.
One reason confusion may arise is how we can look at the same thing
and see it in different ways. I can look again at “should”, and
merely as an object of my attention, claim it is therefore “a
thing”. The fact that I am talking about it is sufficient for it to
be a thing. I can ask, “But what is ‘should’?”, as I asked in the
previous paragraph. This alone is enough for the mind to be
regarding “should” as something; an object of consciousness being
contemplated, and its nature; this or that property or condition
being ascribed to it.
If you accept that everything is a thing, it can lead to certain “paradoxes of totality”. One immediate thing that is lacking in an ontology of things is the notion of types or classes of things. It is interesting to imagine a world in which there is no way to classify or categorize things, but everything is just its own individual, isolated instance; but assuming we are going to, again, it’s like we’re introducing a second “type” into our ontology: there are things, but there are other things than “things”. And yet, if “thing” is by definition a universal category, it seems like we have to differentiate between “things within our ontology”, and a second, more fundamental category of “thing”, which is anything. We can also ask weird questions like, given that everything is a thing, does that make “thing” a type? Is everything of type ‘thing’? But also, is ‘type’ a thing? Is it a thing of type ‘type’? One can imagine there could be some paradoxes built in this way.

So maybe we can ask: what are our options for “upper ontologies” - which categories seem necessary, and which can be surprisingly rejected - things, classes, types, relationships, states, aspects, etc? Do upper ontologies have to be “inconsistent or incomplete”?
And, do the dialectics of “thing” show us that, contrary to first appearances, it actually cannot function as a simple, indivisible concept in an ontology, but is actually a composite of other more specific categories (like type, instance, etc.)?

Foundational types in the sense of modern type theory are not categories, yet categories could be said to be some type depending on their constitution and ruliad. A good category in the sense of modern category theory usually has good pairs of left and right adjoint functors such as those free-attentive vs forgetful or most-general vs glued-together with another nice category as its dual to achieve bisimulation or insofar as both construction and reasoning...

You need to precise the definition of thing, this might help.

@DoubleKnot Nice. What's your background - are you a mathematician? In your comment I think I need some disambiguation, since the words "type" and "category" have separate philosophical vs. mathematical meanings. Are you saying "mathematical types cannot be considered a kind of philosophical category"?


"In this sort of predicament, always ask yourself: How did we learn
the meaning of this word ("good", for instance)? From what sort of
examples? In what language-games? Then it will be easier for you to
see that the word must have a family of meanings."
-Wittgenstein.

What you are asking is equivalent to 'Is pointing a good way to communicate?'
You may not know the I think interesting origins of the word:

thing (n.)
Middle English thing, from Old English þing, þingc "meeting, assembly,
council, discussion," also "action, deed to be done." In late Old
English, "concrete inanimate object; that which exists by itself;
entity, being, creature;" also "event."
The sense evolution probably is from the notion of the "matter" or
subject of deliberation in an assembly. Compare French chose, Spanish
cosa "thing," from Latin causa "judicial process, lawsuit, case" (see
cause (n.)); Latin res "affair, thing," also "case at law, cause."
It is reconstructed to be from Proto-Germanic *thinga- "assembly"
(source also of Old Frisian thing "assembly, council, suit, matter,
thing," Middle Dutch dinc "court-day, suit, plea, concern, affair,
thing," Dutch ding "thing," Old High German ding "public assembly for
judgment and business, lawsuit," German Ding "affair, matter, thing,"
Old Norse þing "public assembly").
The Germanic word is perhaps (Watkins, Boutkan) literally "appointed
time," from a PIE *tenk- (1), from root *ten- "stretch," perhaps on
notion of "stretch of time for a meeting or assembly."
The sense of "meeting, assembly" disappeared by early Middle English
but is preserved in second element of hustings and in Icelandic, as in
Althing, the nation's general assembly.
In reference to a living creature or person by early 12c., often
affectionately or pityingly (young thing is from c. 1200). Thing has
been used colloquially since c. 1600 to indicate what inanimate object
the speaker can't name at the moment, often with meaningless
elaborating suffixes (see thingamajig).
Related: Things (c. 1300 as "personal possessions"). Adjective thingal
(1857) is rarely used. The thing "what's stylish or fashionable" is
recorded from 1762. The phrase do your thing "follow your particular
predilection," though associated since 1960s with hippie-speak, is
attested from 1841 (Emerson).
-from Etymonline entry

So you could say the thing about 'thing' is it's literally a kind of moot point! Many Viking meeting places still exist as placenames, like Thingwall near Livepool, or Thingvellir in Iceland. These are equivalent to Anglo Saxon moot hills and moot halls.
You may be interested in considering Kant's Thing-in-itself.
Heidegger wrote a book, 'What is a Thing?', from which is derived Thing Theory:

"Thing theory is a branch of critical theory that focuses on
human–object interactions in literature and culture. It borrows from
Heidegger's distinction between objects and things, which posits that
an object becomes a thing when it can no longer serve its common
function."
-from Thing Theory article on Wikipedia

The SEP has an article on The Metaphysics of Mass Expressions, on the difference between stuff and things.
You can see a discussion of the topic on here: Do philosophers analyze the term 'thing'?
Edited to add:
Something I'm not seeing discussed is that it's vagueness allows it to be a useful and versatile place-holder. This could be usefully related to the powers of fuzzy-logic.
Postscript: The thing is, doing your thing is very much the thing..! ;)

I'd say the fundamental feature of a thing is that you limit the space of what you're talking about, so you draw some boundaries around a set of features and properties and before you can say anything useful about that or give it a name you've already established that there is a connection between them and that they belong together and are at least somewhat distinct from the things around them.
In that sense I'd say there is certainly some utility to using the category of a "thing". Though the fact that you can apply that near universally and to pretty much anything and everything, as there is always something and even if not, that's still a nothing; also means that it's a category so meta that you can't really derive much information from it about "the thing".
Not to mention that it have large overlaps with words such as "object", "concept" or "entity". Which also look at the same task of encapsulating something. Now personally I'd usually use "object" for "physical objects", "concept" for mental structures such as ideas or thoughts and "entity" for agents that interact with their environment.
But it's fairly simply to abstract from the particular (physical) object to the concept of a thing, like how the concept is an object of the mind and the physical object embodies the concept of encapsulation. Or how speaking of it in active language makes it sound as if the object is some sort of non-physical entity, which is an interesting concept, and so on.
Like if you read the etymology of "thing" that CriglCragl has given then it's fairly obvious how a lot of abstraction has taken place with regards to the word thing. Most likely because a thing (meeting) was thing (topic) that lots of people were excited about, but when talking about the thing (the word), they had different things (concepts) in mind. You know for some it's the meeting, the gathering, the social interactions the things (events and activities) that go along with it, for others who weren't present but only heard about it, the thing (most important part) about the thing (meeting) was things (agenda items) that people discusses about. So breaking things (problems, concepts, proposals, etc...) down to things (agenda items) likely also shaped the meaning of thing (the word).
So everyone is talking about an encapsulation of features and everyone takes something different from it, so the last thing that remains is the encapsulation idea itself.

Do upper ontologies have to be “inconsistent or incomplete”?
Yes.
This was proved in 1933, the proof is known as Tarski’s undefinability theorem. It states that in any sufficiently strong formal system, such as yours, truth in the standard model cannot be defined within the system. In particular there will be ‘things’ (for want of a better word), where the truth statement “this ‘thing’ is a thing”, is indeterminate.

Everything is a thing unless it is not a thing, like time, reason and being.
It will have to suffice for now to say that the ground of things – entities – things that are, i.e. beings, is being.  It makes them be.
Being cannot be an entity because it would be in its own ground. Therefore

‘Being’ cannot indeed be conceived as an entity; enti nun additur
aliqua natura: nor can it acquire such a character as to have the
term “entity” applied ‘to it. GA2
23

Heidegger brings together being and time in his analysis of Kant's Critique of Pure Reason. Starting basically that one thought must follow another, or a thought must unfold, so there is time.

Time and the "I think" are no longer opposed to one another as unlike
and incompatible; they are the same. Thanks to the radicalism with
which, in the laying of the foundation of metaphysics, Kant for the
first time subjected time and the "I think," each taken separately, to
a transcendental interpretation, he succeeded in bringing them
together in their primordial identity — without, to be sure, having
seen this identity expressly as such. GA3 197

And thirdly, being's abyssal ground. The ab-grund (abyss), ground-less, without ground, both reason and being.

"Only when we contemplated what λόγος meant for Heraclitus in early
Greek thinking did it become clear that this word simultaneously names
being and ground/reason, naming both in terms of their
belonging-together." GA10 112

The thinglessness of ground exempts it from the principle of grounding.  Only things are grounded.
Being isn't a concoction of time and reason, because only entities are. Boom boom.
Postscript
The vagueness of this concoction is inevitable.
OP: "Do upper ontologies have to be “inconsistent or incomplete”?"

In the course of pointing to the history of thinking as the Geschick
of being, we constantly spoke of "being" and "ground/reason" because it
was unavoidable. What these words say can never be drawn together and
packaged in a definition. To intend to do such a thing would be to
pretend to be able to smoothly and nonchalantly grasp all the essential
determinations of "being" and "ground/reason," and of being able to do
this in a representation that would hover above time. But so
conceived, the temporal would be the particular, limited actualization
of the supratemporal contents of the definition. [GA10 95]


'Things' don't exist in the ontological world. A 'thing' is merely a mental construct created by focal segregation: a form of attention that separates a specific foreground from the vague, generalized background. Focus one way and a thing appears from the background; focus another way, and that thing disappears while another arises. Types, classes, relationships, states, objects, etc, are qualified focal segregations, which pick out specific qualities of groups or individuals.  Thus we first focus our attention and segregate a 'thing', then we shift our attention to segregate particular qualities of that 'thing' and classify it as a 'horse', a 'chair', or 'our friend Molly'.
Introspection creates interesting effects, like evoking thoughts, emotions, actions, or selves as 'things'. But that's not a qualitative difference, just a convolution.
If you try to derive 'thingness' from ontological precepts you'll end up in a quagmire of confusion. Just sayin'…

If one could forbear to "segregate particular qualities" and desist from instantiating things one would be in full-on meditation mode. The closest one might get to pure being. One just becomes a body.

See Object:

One task of metaphysics is to carve reality into categories. Some things could have failed to exist; they fall under the category contingent being. Some are events; they fall under event. And so on. One might well wonder—is there a category under which every thing falls? Offering an informative account of such a category is no easy task. For nothing would distinguish things that fall under it from those that don’t—there being, after all, none of the latter. It seems hard, then, to say much about any fully general category; and it would appear to do no carving or categorizing or dividing at all. Nonetheless there are candidates for such a fully general office, including thing, being, entity, item, existent, and—especially—object.

Thus, we have several related concepts, being, things, objects.
Is objects the supreme category of being? If so, what are things?

an inanimate object distinguished from a living being; the concrete entity as distinguished from its appearances; a spatial entity.


If we can enrich this question with a bit of humor and paint it in a broader scope; an interesting key to its understanding can be found in Eastern Philosophy where inherent 'thingness' is definitely not a thing.
"A thing can only be a thing because otherwise it is another thing".

"Things in fact lack essence, according to Nagarjuna, they have no
fixed nature, and indeed it is only because of this lack of essential,
immutable being that change is possible, that one thing can transform
into another. Each thing can only have its existence through its lack
(sunyata) of inherent, eternal essence. With this new concept of
“emptiness,” “voidness,” “lack” of essence, “zeroness,” this somewhat
unlikely prodigy was to help mold the vocabulary and character of
Buddhist thought forever".[1]

